# Unable to get page source of the page generated by JavaScript

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

```
 import scrapy
 from scrapy import Spider
 from scrapy.http import TextResponse
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
 from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


 class ExtractSpider(Spider):
     name = "extract"
     # handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
     header = {
         "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36",
         'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
         'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
         'Connection': 'keep-alive',
         'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
         'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
         'TE': 'Trailers',
      }

     # handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
     allowed_domains = ['bniconnectglobal.com']
     start_urls = ["https://www.bniconnectglobal.com/login"]

     def __init__(self):
         self.username = "test@test.in"
         self.password = "test@123"

         self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
         self.browser.implicitly_wait(5)
         time.sleep(2)

         self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
         self.options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")

         # launch bni
         self.browser.get("https://www.bniconnectglobal.com/login/")
         # self.browser.maximize_window()

    

     def parse(self, response):
         self.browser.get(response.url)
         print(f"======================={self.browser.get(response.url)}==================") --> Returns None
         res = response.replace(body=self.browser.page_source)
         print(f"response is {res}")
    
         page = res.url.split("/")[-2]
         filename = f'quotes-{page}.html'
         with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(res.body)
         self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

I am using selenium with scrapy for scraping the dynamic website. But I can't scrape the response. It returns None. But, I checked some different website URLs, and I am able to get the Html response. This one I couldn't get the response. I tried using scrapy middleware and some other questions in SO, won't work. Help me to got solve this.

This response in Html is `<noscript>If you're seeing this message, that means <strong>JavaScript has been disabled on your browser</strong>, please <strong>enable JS</strong> to make this app work. </noscript>`

Below, my error log:-

```
                Scrapy crawl extract
                2022-10-31 14:42:55 [scrapy. Utils. Log] info: scrapy 2.7.0 started (bot: web_scrape)
                2022-10-31 14:42:55 [scrapy. Utils. Log] info: versions: lxml 4.9.1.0, libxml2
                2.9.14, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.6.0, w3lib 2.0.1, twisted 22.8.0, python 3.10.6
                (main, aug 10 2022, 11:40:04) [gcc 11.3.0], pyopenssl 22.1.0 (openssl 3.0.5 5 jul
                2022), cryptography 38.0.1, platform linux-5.19.0-76051900-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
                2022-10-31 14:42:55 [scrapy. Crawler] info: overridden settings:
                {'bot_name': 'web_scrape',
                'newspider_module': 'web_scrape. Spiders',
                'request_fingerprinter_implementation': '2.7',
                'spider_modules': ['web_scrape. Spiders'],
                'twisted_reactor':
                'twisted. Internet. Asyncioreactor. Asyncioselectorreactor'}
                2022-10-31 14:42:55 [asyncio] debug: using selector: epollselector
                2022-10-31 14:42:55 [scrapy. Utils. Log] debug: using reactor:
                twisted. Internet. Asyncioreactor. Asyncioselectorreactor
                2022-10-31 14:42:55 [scrapy. Utils. Log] debug: using asyncio event loop:
                asyncio. Unix_events. _unixselectoreventloop
                2022-10-31 14:42:55 [scrapy. Extensions. Telnet] info: telnet password:
                efa4540ef2aa532d
                2022-10-31 14:42:56 [scrapy. Middleware] info: enabled extensions:
                ['scrapy. Extensions. Corestats. Corestats',
                'scrapy. Extensions. Telnet. Telnetconsole',
                'scrapy. Extensions. Memusage. Memoryusage',
                'scrapy. Extensions. Logstats. Logstats']
                2022-10-31 14:42:56 [wdm] info: ====== webdriver manager ======
                2022-10-31 14:42:56 [wdm] info: get latest chromedriver version for google-chrome 107.0.5304
                2022-10-31 14:42:56 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: starting new https connection (1): chromedriver. Storage. Googleapis. Com:443
                2022-10-31 14:42:56 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug:
                https: //chromedriver. Storage. Googleapis. Com:443 "get
                /latest_release_107.0.5304 http/1.1" 200 13
                2022-10-31 14:42:56 [wdm] info: driver
                [/home/yabesh/. Wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/107.0.5304/chromedriver] found in cache
                2022-10-31 14:42:56 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: post
                http: //localhost:37469/session {"capabilities": {"firstmatch": [{}],
                "alwaysmatch": {"browsername": "chrome", "pageloadstrategy": "normal",
                "goog: chromeoptions": {"extensions": [], "args": []}}}}
                2022-10-31 14:42:56 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: starting new http
                connection (1): localhost:37469
                2022-10-31 14:42:57 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: http: //localhost:37469 "post /session http/1.1" 200 752
                2022-10-31 14:42:57 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: remote response: status=200 | data={"value": {"capabilities": {"acceptinsecurecerts": false, "browsername": "chrome", "browserversion": "107.0.5304.68", "chrome": {"chromedriverversion": "107.0.5304.62 (1eec40d3a5764881c92085aaee66d25075c159aa-refs/branch-heads/5304@{#942})", "userdatadir": "/tmp/. Com. Google. Chrome. Lzraxl"}, "goog: chromeoptions": {"debuggeraddress": "localhost:37291"}, "networkconnectionenabled": false, "pageloadstrategy": "normal", "platformname": "linux", "proxy": {}, "setwindowrect": true, "strictfileinteractability": false, "timeouts": {"implicit":0, "pageload":300000, "script":30000}, "unhandledpromptbehavior": "dismiss and notify", "webauthn: extension: credblob": true, "webauthn: extension: largeblob": true, "webauthn: virtualauthenticators": true}, "sessionid": "3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df"}} | headers=httpheaderdict({'content-length': '752', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
                2022-10-31 14:42:57 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: finished request
                2022-10-31 14:42:57 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: post http: //localhost:37469/session/3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df/timeouts {"implicit": 5000}
                2022-10-31 14:42:57 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: http: //localhost:37469 "post /session/3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df/timeouts http/1.1" 200 14
                2022-10-31 14:42:57 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: remote response: status=200 | data={"value": null} | headers=httpheaderdict({'content-length': '14', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
                2022-10-31 14:42:57 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: finished request
                this line js
                2022-10-31 14:42:59 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: post http: //localhost:37469/session/3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df/url {"url": "https: //www. Bniconnectglobal. Com/login/"}
                2022-10-31 14:43:00 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: http: //localhost:37469 "post /session/3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df/url http/1.1" 200 14
                2022-10-31 14:43:00 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: remote response: status=200 | data={"value": null} | headers=httpheaderdict({'content-length': '14', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
                2022-10-31 14:43:00 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: finished request
                2022-10-31 14:43:02 [wdm] info: ====== webdriver manager ======
                2022-10-31 14:43:02 [wdm] info: get latest chromedriver version for google-chrome 107.0.5304
                2022-10-31 14:43:02 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: starting new https connection (1): chromedriver. Storage. Googleapis. Com:443
                2022-10-31 14:43:02 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: https: //chromedriver. Storage. Googleapis. Com:443 "get /latest_release_107.0.5304 http/1.1" 200 13
                2022-10-31 14:43:02 [wdm] info: driver [/home/yabesh/. Wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/107.0.5304/chromedriver] found in cache
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: post http: //localhost:39887/session {"capabilities": {"firstmatch": [{}], "alwaysmatch": {"browsername": "chrome", "pageloadstrategy": "normal", "goog: chromeoptions": {"extensions": [], "args": []}}}}
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: starting new http connection (1): localhost:39887
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: http: //localhost:39887 "post /session http/1.1" 200 752
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: remote response: status=200 | data={"value": {"capabilities": {"acceptinsecurecerts": false, "browsername": "chrome", "browserversion": "107.0.5304.68", "chrome": {"chromedriverversion": "107.0.5304.62 (1eec40d3a5764881c92085aaee66d25075c159aa-refs/branch-heads/5304@{#942})", "userdatadir": "/tmp/. Com. Google. Chrome. Tqjwrj"}, "goog: chromeoptions": {"debuggeraddress": "localhost:44441"}, "networkconnectionenabled": false, "pageloadstrategy": "normal", "platformname": "linux", "proxy": {}, "setwindowrect": true, "strictfileinteractability": false, "timeouts": {"implicit":0, "pageload":300000, "script":30000}, "unhandledpromptbehavior": "dismiss and notify", "webauthn: extension: credblob": true, "webauthn: extension: largeblob": true, "webauthn: virtualauthenticators": true}, "sessionid": "8572bb5c922eb3df63866e68d78b49b6"}} | headers=httpheaderdict({'content-length': '752', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: finished request
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [scrapy. Middleware] info: enabled downloader middlewares:
                ['scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Httpauth. Httpauthmiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Downloadtimeout. Downloadtimeoutmiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Defaultheaders. Defaultheadersmiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Useragent. Useragentmiddleware',
                'web_scrape. Middlewares. Downloadermiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Retry. Retrymiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Redirect. Metarefreshmiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Httpcompression. Httpcompressionmiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Redirect. Redirectmiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Cookies. Cookiesmiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Httpproxy. Httpproxymiddleware',
                'scrapy. Downloadermiddlewares. Stats. Downloaderstats']
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [scrapy. Middleware] info: enabled spider middlewares:
                ['scrapy. Spidermiddlewares. Httperror. Httperrormiddleware',
                'scrapy. Spidermiddlewares. Offsite. Offsitemiddleware',
                'scrapy. Spidermiddlewares. Referer. Referermiddleware',
                'scrapy. Spidermiddlewares. Urllength. Urllengthmiddleware',
                'scrapy. Spidermiddlewares. Depth. Depthmiddleware']
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [scrapy. Middleware] info: enabled item pipelines:
                []
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [scrapy. Core. Engine] info: spider opened
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [scrapy. Extensions. Logstats] info: crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
                2022-10-31 14:43:03 [scrapy. Extensions. Telnet] info: telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
                ++++++++=======++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++==
                2022-10-31 14:43:04 [scrapy. Core. Engine] debug: crawled (301) <get https: //www. Bniconnectglobal. Com/login> (referer: none)
                2022-10-31 14:43:04 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: post http: //localhost:37469/session/3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df/url {"url": "https: //www. Bniconnectglobal. Com/login"}
                2022-10-31 14:43:05 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: http: //localhost:37469 "post /session/3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df/url http/1.1" 200 14
                2022-10-31 14:43:05 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: remote response: status=200 | data={"value": null} | headers=httpheaderdict({'content-length': '14', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
                2022-10-31 14:43:05 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: finished request
                2022-10-31 14:43:05 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: post http: //localhost:37469/session/3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df/url {"url": "https: //www. Bniconnectglobal. Com/login"}
                2022-10-31 14:43:07 [urllib3. Connectionpool] debug: http: //localhost:37469 "post /session/3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df/url http/1.1" 200 14
                2022-10-31 14:43:07 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: remote response: status=200 | data={"value": null} | headers=httpheaderdict({'content-length': '14', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'cache-control': 'no-cache'})
                2022-10-31 14:43:07 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: finished request
                =======================none==================
                2022-10-31 14:43:07 [selenium. Webdriver. Remote. Remote_connection] debug: get http: //localhost:37469/session/3c3d5ea93d214f19769bb1703e17b9df/source {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `scrapy` but the line `res = response.replace(body=self.browser.page_source)` tells that it receives page source as a text in the body parameter.
You can wait until the page is loaded and then get all the content on the `html` tag as text. And before passing it to `scrapy` add `<html>` tags back. So this will be a complete source of the page.
So the method will look like this

```
def parse(self, response):
    self.browser.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(5)
    html = self.browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')
    source = f"<html>{html.get_attribute('innerHTML')}</html>"
    print(f"======================={source}==================") --> Returns None
    res = response.replace(body=source)
    print(f"response is {res}")

    page = res.url.split("/")[-2]
    filename = f'quotes-{page}.html'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(res.body)
    self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```